# What does Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocator do?

Tags: wpf, prism, unity-container

I know this sounds lame, but MSDN seems to have a bunch of empty information on it. Like this link [ServiceLocator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.servicelocation.servicelocator%28v=pandp.51%29.aspx). I just rolled onto a project with Unity and Prism. I have found it in some code where a WPF UserControl is passed in like this

```
var alert = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<AlertControl>();
```

Is this like Unity's resolve?

Comment: You might also want to check [this link](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://commonservicelocator.codeplex.com/

From the project description:

> The Common Service Locator library contains a shared interface for service location which application and framework developers can reference. The library provides an abstraction over IoC containers and service locators. Using the library allows an application to indirectly access the capabilities without relying on hard references. The hope is that using this library, third-party applications and frameworks can begin to leverage IoC/Service Location without tying themselves down to a specific implementation.

This abstraction is implemented by several IoC frameworks out there, and Unity is one of them. nevertheless, Unity is not the owner of that project.

This way StructureMap, for example, provides implementation of those clases, so other frameworks (such as Prism from patterns & practices) can easily work with other IoC frameworks and not be bound to Unity itself.

Comment: The answer is correct. I'd like to emphasize that the intent of CommonServiceLocator was for use by frameworks and libraries that wanted to take advantage of a container, but didn't want to force the choice of container on the library's users. It's just a standard interface to get objects out of different containers. Despite a lot of the blob posts out there by people who got it wrong, do NOT use CommonServiceLocator in your applications, it doesn't buy you anything and is usually an example of the service locator anti-pattern.